# Parsing a .txt file as different data types

Tags: c#, parsing, types, casting

So I have a text file that reads as the following

```
-9
5.23
b
99
Magic
1.333
aa
```

When I try to read it in using the following code, the GetType() function outputs it as strings:

```
string stringData;

streamReader = new StreamReader(potato.txt);
while (streamReader.Peek() > 0)
{
    data = streamReader.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("{0,8} {1,15}", stringData, stringData.GetType());
}
```

Here then is the output:

```
-9      System.String
5.23    System.String
b       System.String
99      System.String
Magic   System.String
1.333   System.String
aa      System.String
```

I understand that I asked the streamReader class to read it all in as strings.

My question is, how does one read it as the different different data types (i.e. string, int, double), and have it output as:

```
-9      System.int
5.23    System.double
b       System.String
99      System.int
Magic   System.String
1.333   System.double
aa      System.String
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert string to that types:

```
string stringData;
double d;
int i;

streamReader = new StreamReader(potato.txt);
while (streamReader.Peek() > 0)
{
   data = streamReader.ReadLine();

   if (int.TryParse(data, out i) 
   {       
       Console.WriteLine("{0,8} {1,15}", i, i.GetType());
   }
   else if (double.TryParse(data, out d) 
   {       
       Console.WriteLine("{0,8} {1,15}", d, d.GetType());
   }
   else Console.WriteLine("{0,8} {1,15}", data, data.GetType());
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. Why did you use "out," by the way? Why did it have to be passed by reference?

Comment: I have no choice, the tryparse method have that parameter structure. If you want method to return two values is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would know the types (the structure of the file).

If not, use RegEx to check for possible `int` and `double` values, return the rest as `string`.